# Ajax call retuning Json which needs to append into select Box

Tags: json, ajax, select, dynamic, each

I have been struggling with putting my Json data into a select box for hours now, I am successfully able to retrieve my json data inside my Ajax.

Problem is The ID shows up in the select Box as a option with name And I Do not want that I just want names to show and the Id values to stay hidden.

Code i have so far..

```
 <select id="seasontype_select">
            <option value=""> select</option>
  </select>
```

Json Data:

```
[{"value":"1","label":"BrushPickup"},{"value":"2","label":"LeafPickup"}]
```

Ajax:

```
             $.ajax({
            url: 'SelectType.ashx',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json', //make sure your service is actually returning json here
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: '{}',
            success: function (data, status) {


  //Here Is Where I get the Value: ID, with Label don't want that just Label should show 
                     $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                        $('#seasontype_select').append('<option value"' + i + '">' + d + '</option>');


                    });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was Just able to solve this on my own, i figured it out! Besides using

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'SelectType.ashx',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json', //make sure your service is actually returning json here
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: '{}',
                success: function (data, status) {
                        $.each(data, function (i,d) {
                            $('#seasontype_select').append('<option value"' + d.value + '">' + d.label + '</option>');

                        });
                }
            });
        });
```